# maven jboss tattletale report

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am trying to add a tattletale report to a maven 2 master POM.

Ideally I only want the report to run once, but it seems to be run with every module compile.

Is it possible to set tattletale into a master POM and only have it run once on the entire code base? If so, can somebody provide the settings for the POM file so that I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do something like what you're describing is to put the configuration in a Maven profile in your parent pom. Then you can activate that profile on-demand when you build any of your child modules. For example, if you want a predefined configuration that you can use on any of your war modules, you might do something like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>tattletale-war</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.tattletale</groupId>
            <artifactId>tattletale-maven</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Beta2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</source>
                <destination>${project.build.directory}/reports</destination>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Then activate it when you want at the command line:

> mvn clean package -P tattletale-war

Answer (score 0):

Tattletale generates a report based on an artifact, so doesn't that mean a report needs to be made at a Maven module level?

I'm working on a multi-module Maven project, and my plan is to declare the plugin at the top, under  and have it declared for each of the modules I want to report on.